# DM command that are only available to premium users

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm trying to make a command that sends a  message to a mentioned user. This command is only available to premium users. However, even if the user that uses this command is a premium user, my bot will still say *'Oops! This command is only available to premium users.'*. How do I make this command work?

```
@client.command(aliases=['dm'])
async def message(ctx, member: discord.Member, description):
  description = description
  em=discord.Embed(title="You received a letter..", description=description, color=0xe9a9a9)
  em.set_author(name=f"{ctx.author.name} ━ Message", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
  em.set_footer(text="DM a Manager to report harrassment")

  if ctx.author.id == "88877713685543985":
    await member.send(embed=em)
    await ctx.send(f"Your message has been delivered to {member.mention}!", embed=em)
    return

  else:
    await ctx.send("Oops! This command is only available to premium users.")
    return
```

Comment: Please don't add things like "fixed" to the title or question body. If you managed to solve the problem, then either accept the answer that helped you fix the problem, or post your own answer with your solution and accept it after the timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async def message(ctx, member: discord.Member, description):
  description = description
  em=discord.Embed(title="You received a letter..", description=description, color=0xe9a9a9)
  em.set_author(name=f"{ctx.author.name} ━ Message", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
  em.set_footer(text="DM a Manager to report harrassment")

  if ctx.author.id == 848737136855466035:
    await member.send(embed=em)
    await ctx.send(f"Your message has been delivered to {member.mention}!", embed=em)
    return

  else:
    await ctx.send("Oops! This command is only available to premium users.")
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
if ctx.author.Profile.premium:
    await member.send(embed=em)
    await ctx.send(f"Your message has been delivered to {member.mention}!", embed=em)
    return

else:
    await ctx.send("Oops! This command is only available to premium users.")
    return
```

Comment: i tried it but it didnt work